# Variable Indefinida en Python

Tags: python

Estaba intentando crear un asistente personal básico, simplemente para aprender un poco más sobre el lenguaje Python (tengo 16 así que aún no he comnenzado con la programación en clases).

Y me he encontrado con un extraño error que me dice que una variable está indefinida dentro de una función, sin embargo, estoy bastante seguro de que la he declarado, y debería aceptarla.

Aquí os dejo mi código.

```
# Importar Librerías

import speech_recognition as sr # Reconocimiento de voz.

from gtts import gTTS # Conversión de texto a MP3.
import playsound # Lectura de MP3.

# Declarar Variables

username = ""
myName = "Vewi"

microphone = sr.Recognizer()

tts = ""
audioNumber = 0 # Ésta es la variable declarada.

lang = "es-ES"

# Función Presentarse

def ImVewi():
    audioText = ("Hola, soy " + myName + ". Mi trabajo será ayudarte. Para comunicarte conmigo, prueba a hablarle al micrófono. Ahora, te haré unas preguntas rápidas para poder mejorar tu experiencia.")
    TextToSpeech(audioText)
    ChangeUsername()

# Función Obtener Username

def ChangeUsername():
    global audioText
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audioText = ("¿Cómo te llamas?")
        TextToSpeech(audioText)
        print("a")
        audio = microphone.listen(source)
        print("Listened")
    try:
        username = microphone.recognize_google(audio, language=lang)
        audioText = ("Perfecto, ahora te llamaré " + username + ".")
        TextToSpeech(audioText)
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        audioText = ("Disculpa, no te he entendido. ¿Podrías repetirlo?")
        TextToSpeech(audioText)
        ChangeUsername()
    except sr.RequestError:
        audioText = ("Disculpa, se ha producido un error. ¿Podrías repetirlo?")
        TextToSpeech(audioText)
        ChangeUsername()

# Transformar Texto a Audio

def TextToSpeech(audioText): # Ésta es la función con el error.
    audioNumber+=audioNumber # El error lo da en esta línea.
    tts = gTTS(text=audioText, lang = lang)
    tts.save("Audio/Speech"+str(audioNumber)+".mp3")
    playsound.playsound("Audio/Speech"+str(audioNumber)+".mp3", True)

# Llamar Funciones

ImVewi()
```

Debería crear un archivo MP3 llamado "Speech1.mp3" ya que no me deja por defecto sobreescribir los archivos anteriormente creados, por lo que no puede ser simplemente "Speech.mp3" o un nombre predefinido.

En la terminal me da este problema:

> Undefined variable 'audioNumber' // Línea 58, columna 5

También me serviría si alguien supiese otra forma de hacer ésto, o de sobreescribir los archivos MP3 anteriormente creados.

He estado un buen rato intentándolo y no he sabido solucionarlo.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creo que si pones `audioNumber = 0` dentro de tu función `TextToSpeech` debería resolver tu problema

Comment: Lo he intentado, pero ya que la función "TextToSpeech" se ejecuta cada vez, el valor de la variable vuelve siempre a ser 0, creando todos los archivos con el mismo nombre. Sin embargo, éso sí ha solucionado el problema en la terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que añadir `global`a tu variable dentro del metodo `TextToSpeech()`

Codigo de ejemplo:

```
audioNumber = 3

def TextToSpeech(): # Ésta es la función con el error.

    global  audioNumber 
    audioNumber +=1
    print(audioNumber); # Imprimo 4


TextToSpeech() #Si vuelvo a llamar a la función pinto un 5
```

La razon de este error es que dentro de `TextToSpeech()` Python cree que tu variable `audioNumber` es una varible local(y no la tienes declarada localmente). Tienes que decirle que `audioNumber` es global para que la busque en un ámbito mas allá de la funcion

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Ésto ha solucionado mi problema y ya funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Si mi respuesta soluciona tu problema, no olvides de marcarla como respuesta correcta y dejar un positivo. Me alegra haberte ayudado, mucha suerte con la programacion!